# trying to use pyttsx3, getting multiple errors, KeyError: 'sapi5', ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)

Tags: python, error-handling, pywin32, sapi, pyttsx3

My code:

```py
import pyttsx3

#sapi5 is default windows voice api
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    pass
```

On running the code instead of getting that voice ID printed I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\subha\Documents\Personal_Space\Code_Samples\Mavis\jarvis.py", line 4, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)
```

On the other side I had a project based on cv2 that was working fine earlier but now that also stopped working.
The only change that happened recently is that I upgraded to windows11 yesterday. So is that the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't conflict with Windows 11! For me they still are running efficiently! Try to uninstall Python and pip including all modules as well and then download them.

If that doesn't work you, you could try switching to older versions of Python that support these quiet efficiently or you can download these libraries from internet optimized for Windows 11.
Or, if none of these help you can consider switching back to Windows 10!

Note- Windows 11 is still relatively new and there are lot of bugs which different users are facing which may be uncommon for others. I am myself facing some issues which are uncommon and the methods which I prescribed may not work for you!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have tried the code and works fine for me now as per me there is no problem in your code and its probably the windows 11 or the installation has a defect / glitch cause windows 11 is not yet the smoothest and it may be causing your code to not run properly

i would also like to ask you to see if the permissions and stuff are allowed maybe they are stopping access i hope these words have been helpful i have tried my best to understand hope it goes well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31723956)